# Archive Manager doesn't show file with the name "-"

Tags: filenames, zip, stdin

Given that I made a .zip file by piping from stdin like this:

```bash
$ echo foo | zip temp.zip -
```

This produces an archive OK (with the data in a file named "-"):

```
$ unzip -t temp.zip
Archive:  temp.zip
    testing: -                        OK
No errors detected in compressed data of temp.zip.
```

And I can get the data back:

```
$ unzip temp.zip
$ cat ./-
foo
```

However if I open the file `temp.zip` with the Archive Manager (Ubuntu 14.04) I don't see the file:

[image: Archive Manager file list]

And if I try to "Extract" the contents of the archive I get this:

[image: Extraction not performed]

I don't particularly want the file to be named "-" but there doesn't seem to be a way of changing that if you zip from stdin.

Is this behaviour of Archive Manager expected? Or a bug perhaps?

Is there a way of getting the file back using the Archive Manager?

Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2019603/how-do-you-specify-filenames-within-a-zip-when-creating-it-on-the-command-line-f